# Unix Shell - Zip command

Tags: linux, shell, unix, zip

How do I use command zip so that i can compress specific files and other files that start with "red". They're all in the same directory

I'm trying  `zip myfiles bookyhs.txt sholah.txt ^"red"`

having problems with the last part of the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `glob pattern` instead of regex pattern to match all files starting with `red` in current directory:

```
zip myfiles bookyhs.txt sholah.txt red*
```